# Is there a way to prevent WatIn from timing out?

Tags: watin

Due to unknown reasons, the time it takes to log onto the application has grown significantly. This wouldn't normally be an issue; however, nothing I do seems to prevent Watin from timing out.

After the 'Log on' button is clicked, it can take up to 1 minute for the home page to be displayed.  I've tried a few thigs like:

ieInUse.Button(Find.ByValue("Log On")).Click();

ieInUse.WaitUntilContainsText("Text on home page");

or something like...

ieInUse.Button(Find.ByValue("Log On")).Click();

ieInUse.WaitForComplete(100000);

But the tests still fail with the error:

WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException : Timeout while waiting for document state complete. Last state was 'loading'

Answer (score 6):

Use this watin settings to increase the timeout before you initialize the ie object.

```
   Settings.AttachToBrowserTimeOut = 240; //240 seconds
   Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 240;
   Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 240;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely late to answer that but I was asking myself the same question and found an answer on the Watin 2.0 release note :

> Previous versions of WatiN would wait until IE and the DOM document got into the ‘ready’ state. More and more websites never reach this state for instance because of adds constantly loading. WatiN will now wait for IE and the DOM Document to get to the ‘interactive’ or ‘ready’ state to avoid unnecessary time-outs, and to be more responsive.

http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-0-50-11579/

So check the version you are using. Hope this helps someone.